# Vaadin app on Tomcat behind Traefik results in Session Expired

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, traefik, rapidclipse

I have a small Vaadin/Rapidclipse app on a Tomcat server running. As reverse proxy I use Traefik v1.7.4.
If I connect to the Server directly via http://159.69.121.213:8080/TestTraefik/ everything works fine.

**http://159.69.121.213:8080/TestTraefik/ is public and you can test with it directly.**

If I connect via the mycob.int.yyyy.com the site is loaded BUT it appears "Session Expired" immediately.

traefik.toml

```
################################################################
# Global configuration
################################################################
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
################################################################
# Entrypoints configuration
################################################################
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
        [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
          certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/int.yyyy.com/fullchain.pem"
          keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/int.yyyy.com/privkey.pem"
[file]
filename = "./rules.toml"
watch = true
################################################################
# Traefik logs configuration
################################################################
[traefikLog]
 filePath = "log/traefik.log"
################################################################
# Access logs configuration
################################################################
[accessLog]
 filePath = "/path/to/log/log.txt"
################################################################
```

rules.toml

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.mycob2]
    entrypoints = ["https"]
    backend = "mycob"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.mycob2.routes.all]
       rule = "Host:mycob.int.yyyy.com;AddPrefix:/TestTraefik"

[backends]
  [backends.mycob]
    [backends.mycob.servers.tomcat]
        url = "http://159.69.121.213:8080"
```

I can image the problem comes from the PUSH connection. In the post [Session Expired on tomcat8 behind apache2 ProxyPass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519302/session-expired-on-tomcat8-behind-apache2-proxypass) with Apache Proxy it seems that adding the **ProxyPassReverseCookiePath** brought the solution but I could not find such a option for Traefik.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ismail solved the issue for me. Thank you for that again.

The problem was in `/etc/tomcat/context.xml` file of Tomcat.

Adding `sessionCookiePath="/"` to the `<Context>` element solved the problem. Result line is `<Context sessionCookiePath="/">`.